# Getting locations of the variable declarations

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing an extension which requires me to get the locations of the variable declarations.
For example,

```ts
var x = 5;
console.log(x);
```

Does the VS Code API provide functionality like `getVariableLocations()` which will return the position of the `var x = 5;`?

Comment: Do you mean the path of the file the variable was defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the [document symbols](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-symbol) by running `'vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider'`.

Here's an example that executes the command on the active document, and then converts the nested list of symbols (each `DocumentSymbol` can have `children`) into a flat list filtered by `SymbolKind.Variable`:

```ts
function findVars(symbols: vscode.DocumentSymbol[]): vscode.DocumentSymbol[] {
  var vars =
      symbols.filter(symbol => symbol.kind === vscode.SymbolKind.Variable);
  return vars.concat(symbols.map(symbol => findVars(symbol.children))
                         .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []));
}
var activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
if (activeEditor !== undefined) {
  vscode.commands
      .executeCommand<vscode.DocumentSymbol[]>(
          'vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider', activeEditor.document.uri)
      .then(symbols => {
        if (symbols !== undefined) {
          for (const variable of findVars(symbols)) {
            console.log(variable.name);
          }
        }
      });
}
```

When running this on this code snippet itself, it logs `activeEditor`, `vars` and `variable`. You can check the position with [`DocumentSymbol.range`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentSymbol.range).

Comment: I am looking for the breadcrumb string of a file which is the path of it. Am I right here? If so, how could I use the code above to get started? Should I run the code from nodejs within vscode?

Comment: @Timo I think the OP was planning to use this inside of an extension. Some example extensions can be found in Microsoft's examples repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/helloworld-sample