# how to access the text of vscode breadcrumb from extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to write an extension to copy the text / path shown in vscode breadcrumb (marked in blue in picture). But I am unable to find any vscode api to read that. Any help with that?

[image: vscode breadcrumb]

Comment: There's no straightforward way to do that - you'd have to reconstruct it from the document symbols API that VSCode uses under the hood for this. There's a `vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider` command to obtain those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57345173/getting-locations-of-the-variable-declarations

Comment: thanks for the pointer. will explore it.

Comment: SO is so ... wow, exactly what I need. Did you get further with getting a hold on the breadcrumb/file location path?

Comment: no. not actively working on it. didn't explore yet. please post here with your finding.

Comment: FYI, there's a related feature request which you can upvote here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58678

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that you have problem getting the JSON property key path from root to your desired property key, I have recently run into this problem as well with my translations JSON files.

I wrote my own extension for vs code to get the path from root the child. Please give it a try and let me know if it solved your problem.
Click [here](https://github.com/Saibabu276/json-path-finder-bundle/blob/main/json-path-finder-0.0.1.vsix)! check it out and download.

P.S: I didn't publish this in market place yet, since I have test runs to do. But this is a completely functional version.

Comment: thank for for making this extension. I installed and used it. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: glad that I could help 

Answer (score 1):

There is another extension that works for any type of breadcrumb, not just JSON: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=scott-blair.copy-breadcrumbs&ssr=false#overview

There isn't much documentation on it, but after install you can run "Cmd + Shift + P" and type "Copy breadcrumbs".